# dynamically updating a dictionary with parsed in data c#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I've created a dictionary with known key values.

I also have a string message that gets parsed into my program that I split up and store in two different variables, this is done in my `AppendString` method. One part of this string message contains the key value and the other part of the message I split up I want to use to update a stored value held inside my dictionary should the key match it.

However, the values I want to update, aren't updating. Could someone please have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string Value1 = "";
string Value2 = "";
string Value3 = "";
string Value4 = "";
string Value5 = "";
string Value6 = "";

void Start() 
{

    myDictonary.Add("11111111", Value1);
    myDictonary.Add("22222222", Value2);
    myDictonary.Add("33333333", Value3);
    myDictonary.Add("44444444", Value4);
    myDictonary.Add("55555555", Value5);
    myDictonary.Add("66666666", Value6);

}

private void AppendString(string message) 
{   
    testMessage = message;

    string[] messages = message.Split(',');

    foreach(string w in messages)
    {   
        if(!message.StartsWith(" "))
            outputContent.text +=  w + "\n";

    }

    messageCount = "RSSI number " + messages[0];
    uuidString = "UUID number " + messages[1];



    if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(uuidString))
    {
        Value1 = messageCount;
        Value2 = messageCount;
        Value3 = messageCount;
        Value4 = messageCount;
        Value5 = messageCount;
        Value6 = messageCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your dictionary keys start with "UUID number", so checking for `myDictionary.ContainsKey(uuidString)` should always return false.  Try changing this:

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(uuidString))
```

to this:

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(messages[1])
```