# Parsing string logic issue c#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

[This is a follow on from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792330/dynamically-updating-a-dictionary-with-parsed-in-data-c-sharp)

My program is taking in a string that is comprised of two parts: a distance value and an id number respectively. I've split these up and stored them in local variables inside my program. All of the id numbers are stored in a dictionary and are used check the incoming distance value. Though I should note that each string that gets sent into my program from the device is passed along on a single string. The next time my program receives that a signal from a device, it overrides the previous data that was there before.

Should the id key coming into my program match one inside my dictionary, then a variable held next to my dictionaries key, should be updated. However, when I run my program, I don't get 6 different values, I only get the same value and they all update at the same time.

This is all the code I have written trying to do this:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string Value1 = "";
string Value2 = "";
string Value3 = "";
string Value4 = "";
string Value5 = "";
string Value6 = "";

void Start() 
{

    myDictonary.Add("11111111", Value1);
    myDictonary.Add("22222222", Value2);
    myDictonary.Add("33333333", Value3);
    myDictonary.Add("44444444", Value4);
    myDictonary.Add("55555555", Value5);
    myDictonary.Add("66666666", Value6);

}

private void AppendString(string message) 
{   
    testMessage = message;

    string[] messages = message.Split(',');

    foreach(string w in messages)
    {   
        if(!message.StartsWith(" "))
            outputContent.text +=  w + "\n";

    }

    messageCount = "RSSI number " + messages[0];
    uuidString = "UUID number " + messages[1];



    if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[1]))
    {
        Value1 = messageCount;
        Value2 = messageCount;
        Value3 = messageCount;
        Value4 = messageCount;
        Value5 = messageCount;
        Value6 = messageCount;
    }
}
```

How can I get it so that when programs recives the first key, for example 1111111, it only updates Value1?

The information that comes through can be dynamic, so I'd like to avoid harding as much information as I possibly can.

Comment: inside your `foreach()` do you really want to check `!message`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[1]))
{
  Value1 = messageCount;
  Value2 = messageCount;
  Value3 = messageCount;
  Value4 = messageCount;
  Value5 = messageCount;
  Value6 = messageCount;
}
```

use

```
if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[1]))
{
  myDictonary[messages[1]] = messageCount;
}
```

This way, you only update the dictionary entry with the key `messages[1]` and not all of them.

Comment: Be aware that if `message[1]` is not a key in the Dictionary this will create a new key-value pair. Not quite same as OP expecting I guess.

Comment: @Kaf in his code sample, he checks if the key exists. I only suggested he should change the contents of the if statement. I added that check  to be more clear.

Comment: Thank for the code, however I've outputted my strings to see if they update and they no longer do. I changed the the second line to messages[0] as its the messageCount variable I need to pass into my dictionary. Do you have any idea as to why this happened?

Comment: @N0xus Change the condition to messages[0] too. `if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[0]))`

Comment: @ovidiu but in the splitting up of the message, message[1] is the key part of the string. So that's the part I need to check with against my dictionary key (and how you shown me how to achieve), now i need to take the value messageCount and putting it next to the value associated with each key. So changing the if statement to messages[0] wouldn't work as that isn't the part containing the key value I'm checking. Or are you suggesting I add a second if statement?

Comment: @N0xus If i understand correctly, you expect the strings Value1 to Value6 to change when you change the values in the dictionary? This won't happen because the strings are added to the dictionary by value, not by reference. So when changhing `myDictonary["11111111"]`, `Value1` will keep it's original value of "", although you did `myDictonary.Add("11111111", Value1);`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[1]))
{
    Value1 = messageCount;
    Value2 = messageCount;
    Value3 = messageCount;
    Value4 = messageCount;
    Value5 = messageCount;
    Value6 = messageCount;
}
```

should be

```
if(myDictonary.ContainsKey(messages[1]))
    {
        myDictionary[messages[1]] = messageCount;
    }
```

Comment: if an id is not in the dictionary and you don't want to add a new entry for it, this would be the route to go